# Remove subcategories from list of categories on wordpress woocommerce shop page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'd like to remove subcategories ("CHOCOLATE", "CRACKERS", "FRUIT PASTES" "PICKLES, RELISHES AND HONEYS") from the list of categories at the top of my woocommerce shop product pages above my products, please see example:

http://www.partisan-deli.co.uk/index.php/product-category/beautiful-blues/

I have tried various php solutions listed on this website however none of them have seemed to have worked. If I inspect one of the subcategories on the list in chrome them I can hide it by styling the element with display: none; however all the categories in the list simply come up as a.inactive when I inspect them so I am not sure how to target specific examples.

Does anyone have a solution?

Cheers,

M.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: OK, will do, thanks :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think of this?

```
.shop-categories > li:nth-child(2),
.shop-categories > li:nth-child(3),
.shop-categories > li:nth-child(4),
.shop-categories > li:nth-child(5) {
  display: none;
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I think you, sir, are a hero. Thanks that worked great.

Comment: I'm learning a lot from this site, rarely have I asked a question and not got a fast answer :)

Comment: @user8236504, you are very welcome! Don't hesitate to ask more questions to the StackOverflow community, we are all very friendly! :) Keep on coding!